# update other column if duplicate record found in same column using scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark-sql

I have sample data as below:

| id | name | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | ABC | 2020-01-01 |  |
| 2222 | PQR | 2020-01-01 | 2020-06-30 |
| 2222 | XYZ | 2020-06-30 |  |

Now as 2222 found twice, i want to update end_date in row 2 for PQR with duplicate record's start date.

Can someone help doing this using scala dataframe.

Comment: I think this can be done using the lag or lead function. Try partitioning based on id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code, this would solve this. Alternatively this can also be done using lag, depending on your order by expression.

```
scala> sparkSession.sql("select * from temp_table").show()
+----+----+----------+
|  id|name|start_date|
+----+----+----------+
|1111| ABC|2020-01-01|
|2222| PQR|2020-01-01|
|2222| XYZ|2020-06-30|
+----+----+----------+

scala> sparkSession.sql("select id, name, start_date, lead(start_date, 1) over (partition by id order by start_date) as end_date from temp_table").show()
+----+----+----------+----------+
|  id|name|start_date|  end_date|
+----+----+----------+----------+
|1111| ABC|2020-01-01|      null|
|2222| PQR|2020-01-01|2020-06-30|
|2222| XYZ|2020-06-30|      null|
+----+----+----------+----------+
```